# Should beginner programmers use unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit, tdd, codeception

I have been learning PHP for several months now. It is not my first language, but it is the first language I have tried to use for real-life projects. Currently I am writing a web application that can be easy for experienced programmers but is rather hard for me. And the more I write it, the more I realise that I spend more time pressing buttons and entering inputs to test my code than actually writing code. I have heard about unit testing (and other kind of testing) and it got me wondering: does my simple web application need any automated testing or is it a complete overkill? Is unit testing something a beginner can learn or is it only something experienced programmers use correctly? And since I am writing a web application, can all its code be tested or only the small logic parts?

Thank you.

Comment: `"I spend more time pressing buttons and entering inputs to test my code than actually writing code"` - Then why wouldn't you want to automate this process?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, as such it is off-topic. That being said, yes, of course you can unit test your code. Indeed, if you are writing anything other than a small project, **you should unit test your code**. There are [entire schools of thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) that say you should *write your tests first* and *then write* your actual code.

Comment: @Feisty Otter Not going to directly answer an opinion-based question... _but_ what I will tell you is that unit testing is a very important skill to have as a programmer. Efficiently testing your code that is easily understood and approved by others is vital to the success of your program. During the writing of your test cases, you'll notice improvements that you can make, and deeply understand the flow of logic in your program. All of that being said, I think you _know_ my opinion on whether or not you should unit test your code

Comment: in the real world I think test with unit testing isn't possible at all. Because you can't emulate difficult testing situations programaticaly. you can design unit test for very simple situations. but how you can use unit testing for IKEv2 rekeying algorithm for example?...

Comment: @vadim_hr Sorry, but this is *nonsense*. The **core** thing that many people dont get is: unit tests work for testable units. You test each *unit* in isolation and make sure it upholds it contract. But when your "unit" is doing 20 different things, is using 30 different fields to do that ... then you can't unit test that. But not because "unit tests" are not working, but because you created code that cant be unit tested.

Comment: My answer here: the ability for  A) writing production code that can be unit tested and B) writing unit tests themselves - is a skill that needs to be trained. It can take *years* to get you "really" there. So the earlier you start practicing - the better. On the other hand, the key aspect of unit tests is: they give you *feedback* by **running** code. So, when a normal functional test takes you 15 minutes to setup ... you very much want to use use unit tests that give feedback in 3 seconds. But when your production environment is such that you get feedback there in 5 seconds ...

Comment: your need for unit tests is much smaller. Of course, good unit tests are also about automation - preventing you from breaking existing code. Long story short: I think that unit tests are a very helpful mean in *most* situations. But in the end *you* have to figure if they are helpful to you given your context. Nobody can guarantee you that you immediately benefit from writing unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Everything can be tested just fine. I definitely think you should use unit tests if you spend that much time typing input. There is no difference between coding the unit tests and the application itself so experience shouldn't matter. Although it can be difficult to come up with good unit tests that cover all the edge cases.

Comment: everything? I think there wouldn't be BSOD in Windows if everything could be so wonderful.

Comment: @vadim_hr, because some developers testing software manually on Monday morning ;)